# Evento ApplicationEventPublisher que hace?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

El evento:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;
```

envía:

```
eventPublisher.publish(new CreateParticipantEvent(conversation, participant));
```

¿Envía notificaciones a todos? ¿Cómo funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te permite publicar eventos que pueden ser recibidos por `listeners` configurados para ello.

Puedes utilizar los eventos publicados por el framework o personalizados, para lanzar tus propios eventos necesitas 4 partes:

**Configuración**

Declarar el [publisher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/HttpSessionEventPublisher.html) en el web.xml para que pueda publicar eventos en el contexto de la aplicación.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**Evento**

Clase que debe heredar de `ApplicationEvent`, en tu caso `CreateParticipantEvent`. Por ejemplo:

```
public class CreateParticipantEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

  private Object conversation;
  private Object participant;

  public CreateParticipantEventextends (Object conversation, Object participant) {

    super();
    this.conversation = conversation;
    this.participant= participant;
  }

  //GETTERS, TOSTRING...

}
```

También puedes utilizar eventos ya existentes, como por ejemplo, `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent`.

**Publisher**

El encargado de "lanzar" esos eventos, en este caso el origen de tu pregunta. Por ejemplo:

```
public class CreateParticipantEventPublisher {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

  public Notify(Object conversation, Object participant) {

    eventPublisher.publish(new CreateParticipantEvent(conversation, participant));

  }

}
```

**Listener**

El encargado de estar escuchando determinados eventos. Por ejemplo,

```
public class CreateParticipantEventListener implements ApplicationListener<CreateParticipantEvent > {


  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(CreateParticipantEvent event) {

    System.out.println("Fired event: " + event);

  }

}
```

Para utilizar los existentes, simplemente tienes que crear un `listener` para ellos.

Como información adicional, te dejo [aquí](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2) un recurso (en Inglés) con una guía de buenas prácticas para la publicación de eventos.